# Windows Server 2022 Hyper-V killing network card

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server, supermicro

We bought new Supermicro server, with two Intel® X722 Ethernet Network Adapters. We just installed fresh copy of licensed Windows Server 2022 Standard, then installed all drivers from supermicro (our model) page. Everything normally works. Both ethernet ports are connected to network with CAT6 cable.

However, after we added Hyper-V from Server manager (add roles and features), then restarted server, because it was required to do so, second network card shows Network cable unplugged.
Internet on first NIC works normally. But if second card is manually disabled, then reenabled, the error is gone and NIC shows connection. This is not normal, because both network cards should work even after restarting server. We didn't create any virtual machines yet, because of this network problems.

What we tried:

- rollbacking drivers to previous version
- installing all possible Windows Server updates
- creating external virtual switch in hyper-v
- remove hyper-v feature, then both cards works normally

None of these methods solves the problem. It must be something with Hyper-V or Windows Server 2022 bug. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the host machine to use one network adapter and the VMs to use the other network adapter?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Network adapter #1 is for host server and adapter #2 should be used for VMs. That method worked normally without any extra configuriation couple days ago, when I was reinstalling Windows Server 2012 R2 on different older server.

Comment: UPDATE: We installed Windows 10 Pro on server, then added Hyper-V. Both network cards works normally, so it is not a hardware issue. I can confirm that this is Windows Server 2022 bug. As written here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/whats-new-in-windows-server-2022 they changed some Hyper-V virtual switch settings.

Answer (score 0):

We had issues at our facility when implementing Server 2022 Datacenter HypverV hosts. It is kind of dumb that so many steps had to be done to just fix it for us. Each reboot our servers would get stuck in a Public/unidentified network state, and it would take a port bounce to put it back on a Domain network profile. Hope these steps help others. You can try each step and reboot your server to see if it fixes your issue.

**1.** For making a HyperV VSwitch, we went with the new method SET (Switch Embedded Teaming). We disabled the Host OS management option when adding the VSwitch.

```
New-VMSwitch -Name “Vswitch Name” -NetAdapterName "NIC 1",”NIC 2”,”NIC etc” -AllowManagementOS $False -EnableEmbeddedTeaming $True
```

**NOTE:** You can set -AllowManagementOS to $True to give the interface an IP. I've had weird issues when trying to attach an IP to a SET VSwitch interface.

**-NetAdapterName** Will be your network interface names you want to use for your team.

**2.** Go to the **Services** and search for **Network Location Awareness** and set the startup type as **Automatic (Delayed Start)**

**3.** Go to your management interface/Team network adapter IPV4 settings and select **Advanced.** Go to the **DNS** tab and in the **DNS Suffix** field on the bottom, enter in your domain.

**4.** If your still experiencing port issues, try these reg edits.

```
Key 1: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetLogon\Parameters
REG_DWORD: NegativeCachePeriod
Value: 0

Key 2: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters
REG_DWORD: MaxNegativeCacheTtl
Value: 0

Key 3: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters
REG_DWORD: AlwaysExpectDomainController
Value: 1
```

**5.** May not be necessary, but you can try to set the metric of your management interface to be higher than the HyperV VSwitch if the Host is managing the port.

You can check metrics in an admin PowerShell and use the command **Get-NetIPInterface**

Go to your management interface/Team network adapter IPV4 settings and select **Advanced.** On the **IP Settings** tab, tick off **Automatic Metric** and type in your new metric number in the field.

**6.** This step is just a last resort band aid if all the steps tried do not work. You can create this batch file and make a task scheduler task to run it at startup. It will bounce your management interface and force the server to rescan the network. **Management Interface** is going to need to be changed to your management interfaces's name

```
    timeout /t 30
    netsh interface set interface "Management-Interface" admin=Disable
    netsh interface set interface "Management-Interface" admin=Enable
```